# Dataframe.replace() does not replace vlaues in all columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I'm havin a dataframe with json values in it that could look like this (only an example. The keys, values and the amount of data in the json can vary)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[{'0':0.0,'7':0.0,'19':0.0}],
                   'B':[{'0':1,'7':0,'19':0}]})
```

I want to replace the occurrence of every single quote with a double single quote. For that I use

```
df.replace("\'","\'\'",regex=True, inplace=True)
```

After executing this however the resulting dataframe only has the replacement done in the first column. So it looks like this:

```
                   A                          B
0  {''0'': 0.0, ''7'': 0.0, ''19'': 0.0}  {'0': 1, '7': 0, '19': 0}
```

I can't figure out why only column A is getting replaced but column B stays the same.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the pandas version? The latest one?

Comment: No. Still have to use 0.24

Comment: And that is the issue. You need to upgrade.

Comment: I was having some compatibility with other packages but I'll try to resolve them and upgrade pandas. Tahnks

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```